# How can I execute javascript in IE when the address bar is hidden?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm writing some automation scripts for our system and I'm using the browser's address bar to execute javascript.
ex.

```
javascript:$('#myButton').click();void(0);
```

However we have some popup pages where the address bar is hidden. Is there an easy way of showing the address bar or another method of executing javascript on a webpage?

Comment: I've also found that I can get access to the address bar on pages where it is hidden by pressing F11 to go full screen first then pressing F4 to focus on the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F12, go to the Console tab, and paste JavaScript.

But this is far from automation, so you might want to look into tools created for just this purpose, like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)  ;)